# Servidor de correo electrónico no envía mensajes y da error en local

Tags: php, jquery, html, email

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = "xxxx@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Hello"; 
$body = "You have received a message from " . $name . " (" . $email . "):\n\n" . $message;
$from = "From:"; 
$headers = "From:" . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: " . $from . "\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();    

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
    if ($name != '' && $email != '' && $message != '') {       
        if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $headers)) { 
            echo '<p style="color:#66A325;">Thanks! Your message has been sent.</p>';
        } else { 
            echo '<p style="color:#F84B3C;">Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>'; 
        } 
    } else {
        echo '<p style="color:#F84B3C;">You need to fill in all required fields!</p>';
    }
} else {
    echo '<p style="color:#F84B3C;">Invalid Email, please provide an correct email.</p>';
}
```

---

Lo llamo desde el formulario:

```html
<form id="contact-form" [![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1] method="post" action="contact.php">
<input  type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nombre">
<input  type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
<textarea  name="message" placeholder=" Escriba su comentario.></textarea>
<input  type="button" value="Enviar Mensaje">
<input  type="reset" value="Reestablecer los campos">
</form>
```

Este es el código javascript:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#send').click(function(){
                $(this).val('Enviando ...');
                $('#success p').remove();
                $.post('contact.php', $('#contact-form').serialize(), function(response) {
                    $('#success').html(response);
                    //$('#success').hide('slow');
                    $('#send').val('Enviar Mensaje');
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
        </script>
```

El error es:

```
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at &quot;localhost&quot; port 25, verify your &quot;SMTP&quot; and &quot;smtp_port&quot; setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\wamp\www\contact.php on line 22
```

Me da error probándolo localmente, pero cuando lo despliego en el servidor dice que el mensaje fue enviado, pero el mensaje nunca llega al correo electrónico, que problema puede ser?

Answer (score 2):

No tienes configurado las variables SMTP en el php.ini, estas por defecto apuntan a localhost en el puerto 25. Si tu servidor de SMTP no esta en el mismo equipo que la web no podrás enviar con esta configuración, deberás poner la IP y el puerto del servidor remoto

```
[mail function]
; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/smtp
SMTP = localhost
; http://php.net/smtp-port
smtp_port = 25

; For Win32 only.
; http://php.net/sendmail-from
;sendmail_from = me@example.com

; For Unix only.  You may supply arguments as well (default: "sendmail -t -i").
; http://php.net/sendmail-path
;sendmail_path =
```

Comment: Pero por que no envía mails una vez subido a web este codigo??

Comment: ¿Tienes un servidor SMTP en el servidor donde subes el código de la web? Tienes que configurar el PHP para que envíe a través de un servidor SMTP

Comment: si, igual ya lo solucione con otra funcion, gracias

Comment: Sería útil saber cuál era tu problema y cuál fue la solución para posteriores consultas de los usuarios, me parece q aún así me respuesta era la solución a tu problema, deberías de marcarla como solución